# Dividing the count of two selects with sub-queries to get a percentage

Tags: mysql

I've written this query, however it says that each table needs to have it's own alias. What am I doing wrong? As far as I can tell, I have aliased the tables.

```
SELECT (a.total_complete_days / b.total_days) * 100 AS "% of complete days"
FROM
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_complete_days
FROM (
    SELECT email, job_date, SUM(job_minutes)
    FROM jobs
    GROUP BY email, job_date
    HAVING SUM(job_minutes) BETWEEN 200 and 1000
) a,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS total_days
FROM (
    SELECT email, job_date, SUM(job_minutes)
    FROM jobs
    GROUP BY email, job_date
) b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you could simplify your query as

```
SELECT 
    (COUNT(CASE WHEN t.job_minutes_sum BETWEEN 200 and 1000 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) / COUNT(*) 
    ) * 100 AS "% of complete days"
FROM (
    SELECT email, job_date, SUM(job_minutes) job_minutes_sum
    FROM jobs
    GROUP BY email, job_date
) t
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the same? It gives a result of 109%. It should give what % the first select is of the second.

Comment: @Someguywhocodes my bad i swapped the values, check updated answer